# Angular2 redirect using JavaScript?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have build a SPA using Angular2. I want to know how to redirect using ES5. If I use `window.location` then it reloads the whole page. I just want component change.

Seems like I need to use `ng.router.Redirect` but when I call it nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Why to use javascript if angular provides navigate method itself, I don't know about es5 but yes i did in typescript using `router.navigate(['routeName'])` . just give it a try using routing you can change only component instead of loading whole page.

> don't forget to instantiate router in the constructor like this.

```
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['/yourRouteName']);
  }
}
```

for more info see here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

## Update for es5

```
app.AppComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
       selector: 'the-app',
       template: `
          <h1>App!!!</h1>
          <a [routerLink]="['Login']">Login</a>
          <a [routerLink]="['ABC']">ABC</a>
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
       `,
       directives:[
          ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
       ]
    })
    .Class({
       constructor: [ng.router.Route, function(_router) {
           this._router = _router; // use for navigation, etc
           this._router.navigate(['RouteName']) // For navigation ot another component
       }]
    });
app.AppComponent = ng.router
    .RouteConfig([
       { path: '/', component:app.LoginCOmponent, name:'Login' },
       { path: '/children', component:app.xyz, name:'xyz' }
    ])(app.AppComponent);
```

I havn't tried this but most probably this one gona work.

Comment: I get this error ` Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for Route! (class2 -> Route)`. Seems like u missed the provider for the router service.

Comment: have you provide router file in the index.html  and router_providers at the time of bootstraping your app

Comment: as clear from the error you havn't import route on the top of class2. just import it and see error is no more there :-P

Comment: I did provide it. Can u provide a complete example. Because it doesn't work

Comment: i did't know much about es5, but yes if you need i do provide same example using typescript